# Is correlation not required for an URL Performance Test in Blazemeter

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I used jMeter to run Performance Test on Blazemeter before. These were backend API tests. I created the test script in jMeter and uploaded it into Blazemeter. I need to run front-end Performance Tests now.

I came across the option to create a Test in Blazemeter directly. You simply insert the URL and parameters if needed and run it.

https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13261976866577-Creating-a-URL-API-Performance-Test-Creating-a-URLAPI-Performance-Test

What I don't understand is, why do I not have to go through the Correlation process here.

If I record the front-end on jMeter Correlation is required.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the system under test. If correlation is not required - you don't have to implement it in your JMeter test (or whatever other load testing tool you're using). If the system relies on dynamic parameters - you will have to perform the correlation in order to properly simulate the ancitipated usage otherwise you won't simply be able to proceed further than login page or authorization API endpoint.

When it comes to BlazeMeter's URL/API tests it's also possible to implement the correlation as it evidenced by the [Extract Data from Responses](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13261976866577-Creating-a-URL-API-Performance-Test-Creating-a-URLAPI-Performance-Test#extract) chapter from the link you've kindly posted.